# labs.play-with-k8s how to copy file to other node

Tags: kubernetes

**labs.play-with-k8s how to copy file to other node **

[node1 ~]$ scp /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt 192.168.0.7:/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.7 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection

Comment: Normally an application developer doesn't directly interact with nodes at all.  In many cloud environments a cluster autoscaler will dynamically add and remove nodes and manually putting files on nodes isn't sustainable.